# Smoldot + polkadotjs: UnusedProofEntry when attempting to query a contract

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, substrate-connect, smoldot

I'm running a custom smoldot node, synced with a hosted bootnode, in a react-based application and attempting to interact with an ink! contract deployed to the network. My fork of smoldot accounts for an new field in block headers and nothing else. I've attempted to test this with the substrate-contracts-node and with the smoldot main branch, however, there seems to be some issue beteween it and polkadotjs (On the contracts panel:
`t.query.contracts.codeStorage is undefined`)

When attempting to use polkadotjs to query a contract, I receive an error `-32000: Error in call proof: UnusedProofEntry` which is coming from [smoldot, here](https://github.com/ideal-lab5/smoldot/blob/7bb3d7ed199b5eb71e3efdc613847122f85a05a1/lib/src/trie/proof_decode.rs#L320). When using a locally running full node instead of smoldot in my react app, contract queries execute as expected. The query is also successful via the polkadotjs UI through the full node. When I use smoldot, there are unvisited_proof_entries (**only** when querying the contract, transactions work as expected). Any idea why this could be or how to resolve it?

For example, using the default Flipper contract and attempting to query the contract's `get()` function results in the error:

```js
let spec = JSON.stringify(chainSpec);
let provider = new ScProvider(Sc, spec);
await provider.connect();
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
await api.isReady;

const keyring = new Keyring();
const alice = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice', { name: 'Alice' }, 'sr25519')

// load the flipper contract      
const contract = new ContractPromise(api, contractMetadata, FLIPPER_CONTRACT_ADDR);      
const storageDepositLimit = null
const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = 
        await contract.query.get(
        alice.address,
        {
          gasLimit: api?.registry.createType('WeightV2', {
            refTime: MAX_CALL_WEIGHT,
            proofSize: PROOFSIZE,
          }),
          storageDepositLimit,
        },
      );
```

Comment: I suggest to open an issue on the Smoldot repo: https://github.com/smol-dot/smoldot